# openwrt/lighttpd cleaning up CGI: process died with signal 6

Tags: shell, lighttpd, openwrt, cgi-bin

I setup OpenWrt/lighttpd with lighttpd-mod-cgi on 3020 according to documentation. But when I connect to router and open the test.sh script's url from browser, just a white page is shown. 
Checked lighttpd error log to find this:

> (mod_cgi.c.1313) cleaning up CGI: process died with signal 6

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""

echo 'Hello World'
```

lighttpd.conf:

```
server.modules              = ( "mod_cgi" )

server.errorlog             = "/var/logs/lighttpd/error.log"

index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html",

                                "index.htm", "default.htm" )

# mimetype mapping

mimetype.assign             = (

  ".pdf"          =>      "application/pdf",

  ".sig"          =>      "application/pgp-signature",

  ".spl"          =>      "application/futuresplash",

  ".class"        =>      "application/octet-stream",

  ".ps"           =>      "application/postscript",

  ".torrent"      =>      "application/x-bittorrent",

  ".dvi"          =>      "application/x-dvi",

  ".gz"           =>      "application/x-gzip",

  ".pac"          =>      "application/x-ns-proxy-autoconfig",

  ".swf"          =>      "application/x-shockwave-flash",

  ".tar.gz"       =>      "application/x-tgz",

  ".tgz"          =>      "application/x-tgz",

  ".tar"          =>      "application/x-tar",

  ".zip"          =>      "application/zip",

  ".mp3"          =>      "audio/mpeg",

  ".m3u"          =>      "audio/x-mpegurl",

  ".wma"          =>      "audio/x-ms-wma",

  ".wax"          =>      "audio/x-ms-wax",

  ".ogg"          =>      "application/ogg",

  ".wav"          =>      "audio/x-wav",

  ".gif"          =>      "image/gif",

  ".jpg"          =>      "image/jpeg",

  ".jpeg"         =>      "image/jpeg",

  ".png"          =>      "image/png",

  ".xbm"          =>      "image/x-xbitmap",

  ".xpm"          =>      "image/x-xpixmap",

  ".xwd"          =>      "image/x-xwindowdump",

  ".css"          =>      "text/css",

  ".html"         =>      "text/html",

  ".htm"          =>      "text/html",

  ".js"           =>      "text/javascript",

  ".asc"          =>      "text/plain",

  ".c"            =>      "text/plain",

  ".cpp"          =>      "text/plain",

  ".log"          =>      "text/plain",

  ".conf"         =>      "text/plain",

  ".text"         =>      "text/plain",

  ".txt"          =>      "text/plain",

  ".dtd"          =>      "text/xml",

  ".xml"          =>      "text/xml",

  ".mpeg"         =>      "video/mpeg",

  ".mpg"          =>      "video/mpeg",

  ".mov"          =>      "video/quicktime",

  ".qt"           =>      "video/quicktime",

  ".avi"          =>      "video/x-msvideo",

  ".asf"          =>      "video/x-ms-asf",

  ".asx"          =>      "video/x-ms-asf",

  ".wmv"          =>      "video/x-ms-wmv",

  ".bz2"          =>      "application/x-bzip",

  ".tbz"          =>      "application/x-bzip-compressed-tar",

  ".tar.bz2"      =>      "application/x-bzip-compressed-tar"

 )

static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi", ".sh" )

dir-listing.activate       = "enable"

cgi.assign                 = ( ".sh"  => "" )
```

Any help? TIA.

p.s:
yes, the script is executable.

Comment: Is it executable by the `lighttpd` user? Check which user `lighttpd` runs as then log in as that user and try running the script - just with `./test.sh`.

Comment: changing this cgi.assign = ( ".sh" => "" ) to cgi.assign = ( ".sh" => "/bin/sh" ) worked!

Answer (score 1):

Try running the script by hand on the server.  Does it run?  Verify that the first line is '#!/bin/bash' and that /bin/bash is installed on your system.  I am going to guess that it is not installed.  Try "#!/bin/sh" instead on your embedded system.

Comment: changing this 
cgi.assign                 = ( ".sh"  => "" )

to
cgi.assign                 = ( ".sh"  => "/bin/sh" ) worked!